# How to print kafka offsets per partition when using source FlinkKafkaConsumer010 to consumer kafka topic?

Tags: apache-flink

I use FlinkKafkaConsumer010 to consumer kafka topic, create a source as follows.

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer010 source = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010(Config.get("topic"), new KafkaKryoDeserial(BillRecord.class), getKafkaProps());

DataStream<BillRecord> kafkaInputStream = env.addSource(source);

//map operator
DataStream<Tuple6<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Float>> tbDataStream = kafkaInputStream.map(new MyMapFunction());

//create a window to count statistics
DataStream result = tbDataStream.keyBy(0,1,2,3).timeWindow(Time.seconds(30)).reduce(new ReduceFunction<Tuple6<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Float>>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple6<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Float> reduce(
            Tuple6<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Float> value1,
            Tuple6<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Float> value2) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple6<>(value1.f0, value1.f1, value1.f2, value1.f3, value1.f4 + value2.f4, value1.f5 + value2.f5);
    }
});

//create a sink 
result.addSink(new MySQLSink());
```

Now I want to see consumption rate after checkpoint finished, so how to print out kafka offsets of per partition ? Thanks.